# Java how to remove element from List efficiently

Tags: java, list

Ok, this is a proof-of-concept I have on my head that has been bugging me for a few days:

Let's say I have:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("foo");
a.add("buzz");
a.add("bazz");
a.add("bar");

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    String str = a.get(i);
    if (!str.equals("foo") || !str.equals("bar")) a.remove(str);
}
```

this would end up with the list ["foo", "bazz", "bar"] because it would read the string at index 1 ("buzz"), delete it, the string at index 2 ("bazz") would jump to index 1 and it would be bypassed without being verified.

What I came up with was:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("foo");
a.add("buzz");
a.add("bazz");
a.add("bar");

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    String str = a.get(i);
    boolean removed = false;
    if (!str.equals("foo") || !str.equals("bar"))
    {
        a.remove(str);
        removed = true;
    }
    if (removed) i--;
}
```

It should work this way (atleast it does in my head lol), but messing with for iterators is not really good practice.

Other way I thought would be creating a "removal list" and add items to that list that needed to be removed from list a, but that would be just plain resource waste.

So, what is the best practice to remove items from a list efficiently?

Comment: You should use Iterator.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043783/how-to-efficiently-performance-remove-many-items-from-list-in-java?rq=1

Comment: indeed i could remove the 2nd if, but when i thought of it it had multiple if's to remove items from the list, so that's why i thought of the bool and the 2nd if

Comment: Other than issue with index. Are you sure about the (!str.equals("foo") || !str.equals("bar")) . to me this conditoin always pass.

Comment: @mani you're right, it should be && instead. As i said that is a proof-of-concept code, not real code, so i missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three main choices:

1. Use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), since it has that handy [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method on it. :-)

   ```
   Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       if (/*...you want to remove `it.next()`...*/) {
           it.remove();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Loop *backward* through the list, so that if you remove something, it doesn't matter for the next iteration. This also has the advantage of only calling `list.size()` *once*.

   ```
   for (int index = list.size() - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
       // ...check and optionally remove here...
   }
   ```
3. Use a `while` loop instead, and only increment the index variable if you *don't* remove the item.

   ```
   int index = 0;
   while (index < list.size()) {
       if (/*...you want to remove the item...*/) {
           list.removeAt(index);
       } else {
           // Not removing, move to the next
           ++index;
       }
   }
   ```

Remember that unless you *know* you're dealing with an `ArrayList`, the cost of `List#get(int)` may be high (it may be a traversal). But if you *know* you're dealing with `ArrayList` (or similar), then...

Answer (score 3):

Use an `Iterator` instead and use `Iterator#remove` method:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = a.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    String str = it.next();
    if (!str.equals("foo") || !str.equals("bar")) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

---

From your question:

> messing with for iterators is not really good practice

In fact, if you [code oriented to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197) and use `List` instead of `ArrayList` directly, using `get` method could become into navigating through all the collection to get the desired element (for example, if you have a `List` backed by a single linked list). So, the best practice here would be using iterators instead of using `get`.

> what is the best practice to remove items from a list efficiently?

Not only for `List`s, but for any `Collection` that supports [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), and assuming you don't have an index or some sort of key (like in a `Map`) to directly access to an element, the best way to remove an element would be using `Iterator#remove`.

Comment: thanks, but in that case shouldn't it be easier to use a while loop?
like:
Iterator<String> it = a.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
   String str = it.next();
   // code
}

Comment: @DarkW you can use a `for` or a `while` to navigate through the elements of an `Iterator`. Use the approach you feel more comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example will likely cause off-by-one errors, since once you remove an object your list's indexes will change. If you want to be quick about it, use an `iterator` or List's own `.remove()` function:

```
Iterator<String> itr = yourList.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if ("foo".equals(itr.next()) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Or:

```
yourList.remove("foo");
yourList.removeAll("foo"); // removes all
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList.retainAll` has a "smart" implementation that does the right thing to be linear time.  You can just use `list.retainAll(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"))` and you'll get the fast implementation in that one line.